# Failed to connect to mongolab database

Tags: javascript, mlab

Code Sample-

```
const express=require('express'),
    http=require('http'),
    handlebars=require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'}),
    fs=require('fs'),
    mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri'),
    credentials=require('./credentials.js'),
    bodyParser=require('body-parser');

    //connect to databse
    var mongooptions = {
        server: {
            poolSize:5,
            socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } },
            replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 }
        },
    };
    var mongodbUri=("mongodb://user:pwd@ds029831.mongolab.com:29831/project");
    var mongooseUri=uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
    mongoose.connect(mongooseUri,mongooptions);
    var conn=mongoose.connection;
    conn.on('error',function(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    });

    conn.on('connection',function() {
        var app=express();
        app.set('port',process.env.PORT);
        app.engine('handlebars',handlebars.engine);
        app.set('view engine','handlebars');
        app.use(express.static('./public'));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(require('express-session')({
            secret: 'intro skill',
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: {maxAge:900000}
        }));
        var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
            username: String,
            password: String,
            email   : String
        });
        var user=mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
        //routing

        function startServer(){
            http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
                console.log("Server Started at port "+app.get('port'));
            });
        }

        if(require.main===module){
            startServer();
        }
        else{
            module.exports=startServer;
        }   

    });
```

This is the code of my node.js. I am using mongolab for mongodb.
I am running app on cloud9.
When i am connecting to the database using mongoose, it is throwing an error as **failed to connect to 1%40ds029831.mongolab.com:29831**.
App is connecting to the mongolab and after authentication (which is successful) it shows the this error.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your password contains a '@' character? if yes please replace it with %40 and try again, the '@' character should only appear before the hostname.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks dude

Comment: You sir are genius. Thanks a lot. I have been trying to figure out this for last 4 hours, but no luck. Glad I found this answer :)